# Launch a UWP app automatically after installing from an MDM server

Tags: windows, uwp, mdm, syncml

I'm new to UWP apps development and I require to install a UWP app from an MDM server and I need to launch the app automatically, immediately after the installation completes.

I could achieve the installation part from the MDM but didn't found any way to trigger the app launch. I used the following documentation for configure the MDM for installation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/enterprisemodernappmanagement-csp